# Unable to get Events with specific location using restFB

Tags: java, restfb

I am unable to fetch all sports events happening in the state of 
Georgia. Is this the right way to use this, since its currently 
retrieving all events across the country.

```
FacebookClient publicFbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(); 

Connection<Event> events = publicFbClient.fetchConnection( 
        "search", Event.class, 
        Parameter.with("category", "Sports"), 
        Parameter.with("location", "Georgia"), 
        Parameter.with("type", "event"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mention [in the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) of the ability to limit results geographically except `center` (latlong) and `distance` (radius) when the type `place` is defined.

You can set the radial search variables [for events](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dfootball%26type%3Devent%26center%3D37.76%2C122.427%26distance%3D1000) but doing so doesn't appear to change the results.

Comment: We are actually trying to search for events which have been posted from a certain geo location, but as you said I am not sure if this can be achieved with the Facebook API. The location snippet which you have shown above is for a user and is of no use in figuring out what we want to achieve.

Comment: non-standardized location noted. A `venue` of an [`event`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=331218348435) has a different format than a `location` of a [`page`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=31131817744)

Comment: The location based search seems to work only for type=place and not for any other types like event | post